# List the directories modified in the last past 24 hours using `ls` command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I would like to list the directories modified in the last past 24 hours.

So far I have the following code which is used in a script to iterate over the resultant directories:

```
for item in $(ls -lt | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}')
do
....
done
```

The `ls -lt | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}'` commands give me the name of the directories ordered by the last modified. The thing is I would like to filter that result to find only those directories which have been changed in the las 24 hours.

Can you help me?

Comment: Mandatory "why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`"  link: [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: [Scripts: find the files have been changed in last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085958/scripts-find-the-files-have-been-changed-in-last-24-hours).

Comment: find . -type f -mmin -$((60*24)) -print

Comment: Ok, so I should use find command, thanks @KamilMaciorowski .
Doing your command, @atype , I don't get the desired result because I need only the name of the directories, instead of that I get something like this: `./parentdir/childdir/.git/index`. I need only  `parentdir`

Comment: @diens add -maxdepth 1 and  -printf "%f\n", and -type d, because you are searching for directories.

Comment: So something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mmin -$((60*24)) -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: Do you want to get `parentdir/` if `index` qualifies for `-mmin` filter? I think mtime of `.git/` doesn't propagate all the way up to `parentdir/`, so `-maxdepth 1` may or may not be what you want. With it you probe the mtime of `parentdir/`, not deeper objects.

Comment: @atype that command it's that I wanted! Thank you all!